# deploy angular app on aws without using node.js

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services

I have a very simple angular app which I want to deploy on AWS. Currently I have created an ec2 instance with MEAN Certified by Bitnami-3-4-9-0 on Ubuntu. I ssh'd into it and cloned by git repository. But the problem I am facing is I don't want to run it through node server.I don't have any npm dependencies and have no need to add node.js. Is it possible to run it without node server?
Should I use some other AMI instead of mean certified ?

Comment: you could upload node_modules manually!

Comment: is it necessary ? is there no way to deploy it without node.js ?

Comment: no node js will be required when you upload node_modules manually.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [guide](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/deploy-your-angularjs-app-to-aws-s3-with-ssl-3635a62533ab).

Comment: This reference will help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962432/node-js-app-on-aws-for-beginner

Comment: is this [tag:angularjs] or [tag:angular]?  neither of them **need** nodejs, but angularjs doesn't even need a deployment script, it only needs a script reference to the angularjs library and a reference to your code.  The server it is running on is completely irrelevant.

Comment: You can use docker or container server where you can pull the images required for the nodejs and then you can make a container with that and finally you can deploy your nodejs code exposing the necessary ports. Make sense?

Comment: @Claies can you please elaborate ?

Comment: here is an angularjs app : http://plnkr.co/edit/Wq1cUkEwgn2pjuH3ubUZ.  it literally requires the angularjs script and the app.js file.  You could even get away with inlining the app code in the HTML, if you really wanted to.  The server you are using to host your files from is irrelevant.

Comment: [Check the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)  You can deploy your angularjs app on `s3`. It does not require `ec2 instance` either.